# How to use functions in asp-for attribute or @Html.EditorFor or @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am developing MVC website in .Net Core 2.0. In this, I want ViewModel binding but, my ViewModel is of IEnumeration Type. When I want to use functions to in the tag i.e.

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Property.Where(s => s.SomeCondition).Select(s => s.someProperty).First())
```

I get error.I used same with

```
<input type="number" asp-for="@Model.Property.Where(s => s.SomeCondition).Select(s => s.someProperty).First()">
```

That also gives error. Any way to do the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The whole point of the model expression here is to reference a particular property solely for the purpose of creating a name attribute on your input which will line up with what the modelbinder expects when it's posted. Model expressions cannot contain methods because there's no way to bind to a method, and particularly in this scenario, there's no way to bind to a property on the result of some arbitrarily filtered query.